# I want to start my own exchange

Tags: exchanges

I want to start my own exchange like btc-e.com I have plenty of money to invest please guide me in this. I myself have knowledge of php but dont want to experiment on things I want it to up and running in a week or so.

Comment: Who does not want to start own exchange? I also want to start my own google, microsoft and facebook. So I am looking for people who will do this for me as well. But I need it faster then in week.

Comment: related: [What is needed to make a bitcoin exchange?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/17007/5406) [What would it take to create my own Bitcoin exchange?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/18540/5406) [How can I get a new Bitcoin exchange up and running?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3054/how-can-i-get-a-new-bitcoin-exchange-up-and-running)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because orderbook based exchanges are not exactly trivial to implement with all necessary security what you are asking is unlikely to happen in business-wise. Even with the best software developers of the world you could not achieve what you wish within a week or so.

If you have plenty of money to invest and you want hiqh quality, long-term, results for your project, what you should expect

- Lead development time of 2-3 months with 2-3 person team with the following components

  - Orderbook ([open source Buttercoin engine available](http://buttercoin.net/))
  - User account management
  - Deposit and withdrawal
- A way to get fiat currency in and out from your exchange (you probably should have a special deal with a bank)
- If you are using western world senior software developers, expect cost between 25 k - 100 kUSD

Also I recommend not to use PHP or ASP.NET programming frameworks, pick Ruby, Python or JavaScript instead. PHP systems have historical record of being prone to hacks and that's something you do not want with financial systems like Bitcoin; using PHP would greatly diminish the trustability of your service. Bitcoin users have become aware of shady services and they most likely want to see that the service you deliver can be trusted before they put in their money into it.

Based on how you set the question it seems that you do not have much experience with software development, so my suggestion is that you hire a project manager who would do the planning for you.