# How can I create an exchange in a foreign country?

Tags: wallet, security, exchanges, development, trading

New to stack exchange this is my first post so sorry if its rough.

I'm part of a project interested in bringing BTC and crypto trading to Angola. We aren't sure where to start or what the best route to take is ie: create an exchange or wallet that allows P2P mobile transactions. We have a great team in place and some serious interest + investors but lack the technical expertise.

I'm looking to speak to individuals interested and knowledgeable about trading Bitcoin for AOA in Angola. Also if you have any general / technical knowledge on Africa / BTC we would love to chat or bring you on board. 
Thanks so much.

Comment: here is some prvious discussion: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/52974/bitcoin-exchanges-website?noredirect=1#comment61607_52974

Comment: Thanks so much. Only problem is since I am new I do not have enough reputation to comment on someone else's post / question to create a dialogue I can only read. :(

Comment: Here's some other previous discussion: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/3054/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/18540/5406, http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/17007/5406, however I must admit that your question is not a great fit for this platform. It sounds more like you want a discussion thread which we can't really provide here: We're actually in the business of focused questions and corresponding answers. ;) When you have a little more reputation, you could join our [chat], or perhaps you can break down your topic into more specific parts.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not ask a question so much as it is soliciting for employees/partners in a business venture.